# DotVVM - How to integrate/reference DevExpress webforms controls in DotVVM pages?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, dotvvm

I have a webforms app that uses asp.net controls and devexpress controls. The page is already converted to use the DotMVVM "dot" prefix instead of "asp" and I need to adjust also the "dx" prefix for all the DevExpress controls.

In the original webforms page the registry was done on the top of the page using:
`<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v19.1, Version=19.1.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX" Namespace="**DevExpress**.Web" TagPrefix="**dx**" %>`

The controls appear in the aspx code like this:
`<**dx**:ASPxRibbon ID="ribbon" ...`
But now, it must be adjusted to be used in the DotVVM context. How?

Already tryed to register the component in the web.config file:
`<pages> <controls> <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v19.1, Version=19.1.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXX" namespace="**DevExpress.Web**" tagPrefix="**dx**"/> </controls> </pages>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, DotVVM cannot use components developed for ASP.NET Web Forms - it is a completely different framework with different control model.

1. DotVVM has a similar set of components to what DevExpress or Telerik have. It is called [DotVVM Business Pack](https://www.dotvvm.com/products/dotvvm-business-pack). You can find many similar components there.
2. Alternatively, you can integrate React version of DevExpress components and wrap them using [DotVVM React integration](https://www.dotvvm.com/docs/4.0/pages/concepts/client-side-development/integrate-third-party-controls/react). It may not be easy to wrap all the components, but if you use just a few of them, it might be the way to go. Please note that this requires some JavaScript skills, and some complex controls like GridView would probably be difficult to cover completely.

Please let us know what is your scenario at [Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/riganti/dotvvm) - we'll be happy to help.